# Canceling Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, abort, thread-abort

I am trying to cancel multiple threads at the click of a button in WinForms. My threading method is listed below, which the thread then calls another method. I created the thread as a class variable and then loops through and creates a new one for however many threads the user wants. I want to stop call threads at the click of a stop button. I could not find any similar questions. Originally, in my `generate()` method below, I would check if the button was clicked and would `Abort()`, but this only works if the button is clicked then and there.

```
private static Thread t;
```

```
  private void threader()
        {


            int wait = (int)(waiter.Value * 60000);
            for(int i = 0; i < numOfThread.Value; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(generateBlizz));
                    t.IsBackground = true;
                    
                    t.Start();
                }catch(ThreadAbortException e)
                {

                }

            }
```

Comment: Don't cancel/abort threads, instead you have them cooperatively finish. You can use something like a `CancellationToken` to make your life easier  in this respect. Also unless you know you need it, you should always prefer Tasks over the ye-old Thread Class

Comment: What is the major difference in Task and Thread?

Comment: I found an article that I will read about them. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: So what does the `generateBlizz` contains. If you use a `ManualResetEvent` and you check the `resetEvent.WaitOne(0)` in the threads-while loop. You can stop them by setting the waitevent.

Comment: `generateBlizz` a method in another class, which returns a string and prints it to the textbox in the winform. I give my user the option to run as many threads as they want and I want them to be to click stop and abort the threads.

Comment: Whenever you `Abort()` a thread you risk corrupting the .NET run-time memory. Aborting is only useful when you are trying to forcibly trying to exit your app. You must include some mechanism for your threads to be told that they are not longer needed so that they can end themselves.

Comment: Be aware that the [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) method is not supported on .NET Core / .NET 5. Attempting to use it results to a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Comment: Use `Thread.Abort` only as a final solution if the routine doesn't respond to a cancellation request (you can consider it something like the `End Task` option in Task Manager that can kill unresponsive processes). But unless you use 3rd party plugins that you cannot rewrite to support regular cancellation, it's highly unlikely you really need that. And potentially unreliable plugins should be executed in their own `AppDomain` so you can unload them safely after aborting to prevent memory corruption. But starting with .NET Core neither `AppDomain`s nor `Thread.Abort` are supported.